# Save a binary file in the same folder for every PC

Tags: java, file, path, binary

I'm making a game that saves information into a binary file so that I can start at the point I left the game on the next use.

My problem is that it works fine on my PC because I chose a path that already existed to save the file, but once I run the game on another PC, I got an error saying the path of the file is invalid (because i doesn't exist yet, obviously).

Basically I'm using the File class to create the file and then the ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream to read/write info.

Sorry for the noob question, I'm still pretty new to using files.

Comment: Check if the path exists, if not create it first.

Comment: Use the [exists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/check.html) method to determine if the file/path exists, if not then create it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must first check if the directory exists and if it does not exist then you must create it.

```
String folderPath = System.getProperty("user.home") + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "MyFolder";
File folder = new File(folderPath);     

 if(!folder.exists())
 {
    folder.mkdirs();
 }

 File saveFile = new File(folderPath, "fileName.ext");
```

Please note that the mkdirs() method is more useful in this case instead of the mkdir() method as it will create all non existing parent folders.

Hope this helps. Good luck and have fun programming!

Cheers,

Lofty

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [File mkdirs()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs%28%29)

Which will create all the directories necessary that are named in your path.

For example:

```
File dirs= new File("/this/path/does/not/exist/yet");
dirs.mkdir();

File file = new File(dirs, "myFile.txt");
```

Take in consideration that it may fail, due to proper file permissions.

Answer (score 0):

My solution has been create a subdirectory within the user's home directory (System.getProperty("user.home")), like

```
File f = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/CtrlAltDelData");
f.mkdir();
File mySaveFile = new File (f, "save1.txt");
```